# What is the technique called where a browser submits a request and gets back multiple responses?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

Take for example a web client that reaches out to a web service and displays periodic up-to-the minute stock price updates without the user having to submit additional requests.

What is this technique called?  Once I know what it is called, I can search for it.

Comment: AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML ??
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

Comment: websocket programming? signalr?

Answer (score 0):

This is called API consumption.

There are multiple ways and methods that this happens:

The web service might be a RESTful API over HTTP(s).

WebSockets uses the TCP protocol.

XHR = AJAX = XHttpRequest.

Not sure if this helped....

Answer (score 0):

I read [an article about possibly the first use of this](http://jacquesmattheij.com/the-several-million-dollar-bug) the other day which [lead to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292158/http-response-before-request) which turned up the term [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) which has links to many other articles about the technique.

Hope that helps.