# Detecting client-side vs server-side routing

Tags: javascript, routes

When browsing a website is there any way to detect whether it's client-side routing or server-side routing in use, except for checking the network tab (in dev tools) for downloaded HTML documents?

Comment: Yeah, the network tab?

Comment: What is "server-side" and what is "client-side"? You mean full reload vs adding part of HTML into DOM?

Comment: @Akxe Yes, exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473302/1417223

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `beforeunload` event to decide what type of routing that is.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  console.log(e);

  // This is usually used to block user navigation, for example, when they have not saved cahnges
  /**
   * // Cancel the event
   * e.preventDefault();
   * // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
   * e.returnValue = '';
   */
});
```

To detect changes to DOM, you could use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). But I would either useone or the other.