# Cannot access pages with direct url after building project for deployment Spring and React

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

When running my spring app from my IDE and running the React app from within VSCode, everything worked perfectly. I used the `build` script to build my React project, and then put the output into my `/static` folder of Spring. Then I used `mvn clean install` to build the .jar file. After running the entire app from the .jar file, I can access my homepage with localhost:5000. I can also use my navbar links to access different parts of the website, like the Home page and the About page... But if I try to manually enter the url `localhost:5000/about` I get a 404 Not found error.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Spring (webmvc?) application is not configured to listen to different URLs other than `/`. And while it may seem as if the navbar successfully redirects to `http://localhost:5000/about`, in reality the single page application uses JavaScript [client-side routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473302/2148365) to change the URL in the browser, unload the currently rendered page, and load another page.

If you are indeed using Spring MVC, you could (among other options) modify your Spring [static resource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) configuration, modify your [`@RequestMapping`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778129/2148365) to listen to multiple endpoints, or use a [`ViewControllerRegistry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewControllerRegistry.html).